# make last columns of two tables same width

Tags: html, html-table

I have two tables.I want to make last col of **Table A** have the same width as the last col of **Table B**.

**Note :**

- both tables have same width.

How to achieve that?

table A :

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>First column</td>
  <td>Second column</td>
  <td>Third column</td>
  <td>Fourth column</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>More data for the first column</td>
  <td>More data for the second column</td>
  <td>More data for the third column</td>
  <td>More data for the fourth column</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

table B:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>First column</td>
  <td>Second column</td>
  <td>Third column</td>
  <td>Fourth column</td>
  <td>Fifth column</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>More data for the first column</td>
  <td>More data for the second column</td>
  <td>More data for the third column</td>
  <td>More data for the fourth column</td>
  <td>More data for the fifth column</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please tell the these values are dynamically added.

Comment: use JS, get and set the width.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? If you want the columns to have same with, you can set a fixed width on both the columns.. or do you want the tables to have same width ?

Comment: both tables are same width and I want to have width of the last column of Table A equals to the width of the last column of Table B and resize dynamically.

Comment: The width can only be fixed if you want to fix this using css. Or you need to use javascript to track the column width on window resize event ans set to to the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve this using :last-child selector.

Method 1 : Using only css

```
tr td:last-child {
    width:100px;
}
```

Method 2: Using Js
On window resize get the width of first tables last column ans set it to the second table. Handle the border,padding,margin adjustments if required.

Refer the code snippet below.

```js
window.onload = calWidth;
window.onresize=function(){
calWidth();
}
function calWidth(){
var colWidth = document.querySelector('#table1 tr td:last-child').offsetWidth;
var borderwidth = 4;
document.querySelector('#table2 tr td:last-child').style.width = (colWidth - borderwidth) +'px';
}
```

```css
tr td{
border:solid 1px black
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
<tr>
  <td>First column</td>
  <td>Second column</td>
  <td>Third column</td>
  <td>Fourth column</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>More data for the first column</td>
  <td>More data for the second column</td>
  <td>More data for the third column</td>
  <td>More data for the fourth column</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
<tr>
  <td>First column</td>
  <td>Second column</td>
  <td>Third column</td>
  <td>Fourth column</td>
  <td>Fifth column</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>More data for the first column</td>
  <td>More data for the second column</td>
  <td>More data for the third column</td>
  <td>More data for the fourth column</td>
  <td>More data for the fifth column</td>
</tr>
</table>
```